# Ruby fastest way to select button in large table

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, watir

I'm trying to interact with a site that has a large table that looks something like this:

```
    <table id="tblID" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr valign="top" align="left">
                            <td colspan="6" height="10"></td>
                        </tr>

                            <tr><td bgcolor="#666666" height="1" colspan="6"><img src="img.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td></tr>
                                <tr class="GridHeader" valign="top" align="left">
                                    <td width="60"><b>Select</b></td>
                                    <td width="210" colspan="2"><b>Account Type</b></td>                                        
                                    <td width="160" colspan="2"><b>Number</b></td>
                                    <td width="200"><b>Account known as</b></td>                                   
                                </tr>

                                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                                    <td class="normal"><input type="radio" id="radButton" name="radButton" value="1233399,1515636"></td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCTYPE</td>
                                    <td class="normal" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCNUMBER</td>
                                    <td class="normal" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCNAME</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                    <td height="1" colspan="6" bgcolor="#cccccc"><img src=".img.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                                    <td class="normal"><input type="radio" id="radButton" name="radButton" value="2263763,2777747"></td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCTYPE</td>
                                    <td class="normal" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCNUMBER</td>
                                    <td class="normal" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="normal">ACCNAME</td>
                                </tr>
```

This goes on for many hundreds of rows.

My code's aim is to search the rows based on ACCNUMBER, and select the associated radio button. My code does this, but takes a LONG time to do it.

my ruby code so far is this:

```
require 'watir'
require 'nokogiri'
html = browser.html
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
*csv import and loop stuff*
bkacc = CSV[0]

*nokogiri go fast!*

rows = doc.css("table[id='tblID'] tbody tr")
rows.each do |row|
    target = row.text[bkacc]
    if !target.nil?
        cells = row.css("td[class='normal']")
        @pushme = cells[0].css('input')[0]['value']
    end
end    

*watir goes slow*

browser.table(:id,"tblMaintenance").tbody.trs(:valign,"middle").find do |tr|
    temp = tr.td(index: 0).radio(:id => "radButton").attribute_value("value") 
    if temp == @pushme
        tr.td(index: 0).radio(:id => "radButton").set
        break
    end
end
*other commands and loop to next line in csv*
```

The finding of the :value of the button I want to push is very fast with nokogiri, but once found, using that :value to look for and set the button with watir is very slow.

My question is; how can I speed this up? I thought perhaps by using mechanize I could but the syntax escapes me. I'm still very new to Ruby so am probably missing some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the combination of the id and value attribute is unique for each radio button, you could locate the radio button directly. The entire Watir loop could be replaced by just:

```
browser.radio(:id => "radButton", :value => @pushme).set
```

Alternatively, I would try replacing both loops with the following. Finding the row will be a touch slower than the Nokogiri approach, but the code would be a lot simpler.

```
row = browser.table(id: 'tblID').tr(text: /#{bkacc}/)
row.radio.set
```

Comment: The first one; browser.radio(:id => "radButton", :value => @pushme).set, worked great, thanks! 

The second one, though faster than the loop, was still taking 2 minutes per ACCNAME. Also watir was complaining about the use of 'text:', which is depreciated, and suggested using visible_text: which I tried but  that was talking even longer to search with.

Comment: I'll have to take a look into the second one. There's probably some ways we can tweak the Watir performance to be better.